# React-router sub-path rendering not firing the right component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have my routes set up like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Homepage} />
      <Route path="games" component={Games}>
        <Route path=":id" component={Game}/>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('mount-point'))
```

When I hit `#/` it fires the `render()` method in the `Homepage` component. Great. When I hit `#/games` it fires the `render()` method in the `Games` component. Great. **But!** When I hit `#/games/1` (or any other things instead of `1`) it renders the `Games` component. Not the `Game` component! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route config seems ok to me. Are you including `{this.props.children}` when rendering `Games`?

http://jsfiddle.net/8L7fa64w/3/

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/1.0.0-rc3/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.33/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.33/browser.min.js"></script>
<div id="mount-point"></div>
<script type="text/babel">void function() { "use strict"

var {Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link} = ReactRouter

var App = ({children}) => <div>
  <h1>App</h1>
  <Link to="/games">Games</Link> | <Link to="/games/42">Game 42</Link>
  {children}
</div>

var Homepage = ({children}) => <div>
  <h2>Homepage</h2>
  {children}
</div>

var Games = ({children}) => <div>
  <h2>Games</h2>
  {children}
</div>

var Game = ({params}) => <div>
  <h3>Game {params.id}</h3>
</div>

ReactDOM.render(<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Homepage} />
    <Route path="games" component={Games}>
      <Route path=":id" component={Game}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById('mount-point'))

}()</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I think my mistake was to think I'd get a new page for the `/games/:id` page. I guess there's no way to have that but still have those URLs, is there?